# There is no 'Sybase' connect type to choose on 'Select New Connection Type' on DBeaver 5.1.1

Tags: sybase, dbeaver

I would like to connect to Sybase DB with DBeaver tool 
Version 5.1.1

I want to choose 'Sybase' connection type and then I hope that connection should be show on list of new connection type but there is no 'Sybase' to choose has just 'Sybase jConnect' and 'Sybase jTDS only'as capture screen below

What should I do for this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Sybase jTDS. I have successfully connected to Sybase with the jTDS connection type.

Comment: Thank you, I could connect it with Sybase jTDS